# How can I expand an <a> tag into a <div> Tag?

Tags: html, css

I have the following div:

```
<div style="height: 200px">
    <a href="#">Click to View</a>
</div>
```

I want to click anywhere of the div tag and want to activate the  tag means in short I want to click on the Div to navigate the link. How can I do that?

### Update

I have to update my question:

1. I can not define the exact height of my `<div>`
2. I have to use 100% for height for `<a>`

My revised code is like that:

```
<div>
    abc<br><br>        
    <a href="#">Click to View</a>
</div>
```

Comment: your current score is 1337 :)

Comment: @macek yes my current score is that... but i can not understand your comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a Javascript function which calls the Link and attach it on the OnClick event of the DIV Element.

Or try something like:

```
<div id="Idhere" onclick="window.location = 'Link here'">
<a href="leave this blank">text here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You definitely don't need javascript to handle this very simple task.

Comment: But you can definitely use it for that.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick for you

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
}

div a {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
}
```

[See it working here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNFfH/)

Comment: Your solution works fine for fixed height say 200px but if I want to use 100% it will not work... Could you please make some changes to work with **height: 100%;**

Comment: I can not define the height of my div and have to use 100% for anchor's height..... please help me...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the div.

```
<a href="#" class="bigAnchor">Click to View</a>
```

then...

```
a.bigAnchor { display: block; height: 200px; }
```

Comment: Is not helpful for me because I need Div for some other reason.... I need to place some other element...

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
.link {
 width: 300px; 
 height: 200px; 
 background: #fc0; 
}
.link a {
 display: block; /* link as block element */
 text-align: center; 
 height: 100%; /* height for all div */
 color: #666; /* link color */
}
```

```
<div class="link">
   <a href="1.html">Link</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE THE ORDER

```
<a href="#">
<div style="height: 200px">
    Click to View
</div> 
</a>
```

***Note:*** `<div>` inside `<a>` is legal is [HTML5](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links)

Comment: Invalid HTML. You cannot have a block level element inside an inline element.

Comment: @AlienWebguy - I assumed the discussion centered on what was valid and invalid.

Comment: The OP did not specify the use of HTML5.

Comment: @JaredFarrish fair enough, but just because it's legal doesn't mean we should be recommending it. `eval()` and `extract()` are valid and legal too but for the sake of sanity why use them?

Comment: The answer should clarify that this *only* works in HTML5. It breaks in a lot of older browsers still out there.

Comment: @AlienWebguy - I remember when using `DIV` and `SPAN` tags were considered incorrect many years ago. As the specifications continue to evolve, objections like this will recede. There are other, more objectionable things I think than this in the new specs. But they're still the specs.

Comment: @diEcho.... HTML5 is not widely supported yet and should not be the ipso-facto go-to answer. If the anser had been provided that it only works in HTML5 then, fine. However, in the real world today, HTML5 should not be seen as the correct method for 70% of the users browsing the web.

Comment: I am 100% agreed with Guffa. We can not use such solution which is only fit for some browsers...

Answer (score 0):

try to change the anchor css:

```
a.block{display:block;height:200px;}

<div style="height: 200px">
    <a class="block" href="#">Click to View</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean `div.block a`; `a.block` wouldn't match anything in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
a { 
 display: inline-block; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expand `a` to any parent you want using CSS:

```html
<div id="parent">
    <a href="#">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="expand"></span>
        My Link
    </a>
</div>

<style>
div#parent {
    display: relative;
}

.expand {
    display: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
</style>
```